# c char string and stdint.h uint8_t compatability in embedded system

Tags: c++

I need to convert const char[] to uint8_t in C++. What is the best method

a)

```
const uint8_t* a = (const uint8_t*)"string";  // I hate this cast, but it works
```

b)

```
const uint8_t* a = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>("string");  // is this OK, is it safe?
```

Why will this not work?

```
const uint8_t* a = static_cast<const uint8_t*>("string");  // will not compile
```

Comment: Why is this tagged `C`?

Comment: Because it is c style string.

Comment: C-style strings are a feature of the C++ language. We don't tag questions based on where things originally came from but based on where they are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should static\_cast, dynamic\_cast, const\_cast and reinterpret\_cast be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)

Comment: @jmstoker, I did see that but I wanted input for this specific case.  What I am trying to understand is why do I need to use reinterpret_cast to convert a byte to byte?  Why is unsigned cannot be implicitly converted to signed?  It is the same byte?  Also, maybe I should not even use reinterpret_cast at all?  What are the dangers of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second solution is the "Most Correct" way to do it.  The reinterpret_cast will be handled entirely by the compiler and simply point at the resulting bits with a different type.  The first solution is old-style and generally should not be used in modern C++.